# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Tile badge from push notification never cleared on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Worklight 6.1 and sending push notifications to Windows Phone 8.  It is working swell, except for the tile badge.  It is not being cleared when I use the tile to launch the app. The notification that I'm sending is:

```
{"APNS":{ … },"GCM":{ … },"SMS":{ … },"MPNS":{"raw":{"payload":{}},"toast":{"text1":"Luggage Tracker","text2":"You have 3 available messages"},"tile":{"count":3}}}
```

The toast message pops up, and the tile gets the badge, but the badge doesn't clear when I  launch the app, and the only way I can find to clear it is to have the server push another notification with: tile {count:0}

Is there any way for the app to clear the tile badge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the WL.Badge API is iOS-only. I have submitted an RFE to either enhance it or create specialized API for clearing the tile in Windows Phone 8 as well.

So the solution at this time, as I see it, is to [create a Cordova plug-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova) to update the count... I found this plug-in. Perhaps you take from it when you need: https://github.com/sgrebnov/incubator-cordova-wp8/blob/master/plugins/www/plugins/LiveTiles/liveTilesExample.html

---

Use the [WL.Badge.setNumber() API method](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Badge.html).
Setting 0 should clear the badge from the tile.

```
WL.Badge.setNumber(0);
```

You can probably use this in the same logic that handles the received push (the one that shows the `Toast` pop up notification).

Worklight does not provide any mechanism to handle the badges other than methods to set or remove so you need to write one of your own.

Comment: WL.Badge is undefined for Window Phone 8

Comment: Awesome. :) I'll ask the feature implementor about this; if it's a defect, I'll open one...

Comment: @DavidDhuyveter, fixed for Worklight 6.2; setNumber can now also be used to change the number of notifications displayed on the tile in WP8.