# Toast for Push Notification on Windows Phone 8 using Worklight 6.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Worklight 6.1 and sending push notifications to Windows Phone 8 using unauthenticated procedure.

I am creating the notification by using the following procedure. This procedure updates the tile and badge but doesn't generates a toast notification:
`WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, {custom:"data"});`

1. What is the correct procedure for adding a "toast" to a received push notification on Windows Phone 8?
2. Also, is there any way to clear the notification on the tile once the application is launched by clicking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The [WL.Server.createDefaultNotiication](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html%23createDefaultNotification?lang=en) API method returns only the `raw` and `tile` notification types for Windows Phone 8. To add a `toast` notification, see the example below.

   ```
   var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification("You have " + numCoupons + " coupons.", numCoupons, {foo: "bar"});

   notification.MPNS.toast = {};
   notification.MPNS.toast.text1 = "Toast title”;
   notification.MPNS.toast.text2 = "Toast content”;
   ```
2. To clear the number from the application icon, or tile, the `WL.Badge` method should be used. However, in Worklight 6.1 [this method is applicable only for the iOS environment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Badge.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.1.0%2F10-0-0-1-5&lang=en) (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197963/ibm-worklight-6-1-tile-badge-from-push-notification-never-cleared-on-windows-p/21199648#21199648) for a possible alternative).

   Starting Worklight 6.2, [WL.Badge is applicable for Windows Phone 8 as well](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Badge.html%23setNumber).

Comment: One more problem, the props are shown empty in case of Windows Phone 8 as **props:{}** and the notification alert is not shown if I click on the tile or toast.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you completely; if you can supply a sample project demonstrate Only this issue, we can take a look at it.

Comment: [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.Push.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.1.0%2F10-0-0-1-8&lang=en) In this documentation, IBM states for windows phone 8, **Registers a callback method that is called whenever a raw notification or a toast notification arrives and the application is running. If the notification arrives when the application is not running, then the callback method is not called. This behavior is defined in the Microsoft OS and cannot be changed**. Is there any way to show alert on app launch??

Comment: And for the props, i tried it on sample push notification project provided at Getting started with worklight 6.1. I simply added windows phone 8 environment and configured unauthenticated push. The props are always null but payload is received fine!