# registerEventSourceCallback function issue in ibm mobilefirst for windows phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am running the sample push notification hybrid project provided by IBM in windows phone environment . I receive the notification alert when the app is running, but not when the app is in background in the windows emulator.I am using unauthenticated push service.
This sample project works fine for me in android and ios.

I referred the following links :
[Toast for Push Notification on Windows Phone 8 using Worklight 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583133/toast-for-push-notification-on-windows-phone-8-using-worklight-6-1)

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.Push.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.1.0%2F10-0-0-1-8&lang=en

"If the notification arrives when the application is not running, then the callback method is not called."

Is there a workaround for this whereby i can receive the notification even when the app is not running in windows phone?

Also, I am receiving the props as empty.

I am currently using MobileFirst 7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Worklight perspective this cannot be changed, because this is how Microsoft defined how should push notifications work in their product.

Comment: Thank you Idan for your reply. Any idea why the props show empty for windows app? I do not get empty props field in android emulator